# WebSocket always sending stringified JSON object as buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a node/ws WebSocket server listening for messages on a Redis backplane, and then forwards it on to any client that is listening:

```
sub.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    console.log('received message from redis: ' + message);
    console.log('message is type ' + typeof(message));
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(message);
    console.log('stringified is type ' + typeof(stringified));

    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      client.send(stringified);
    });
});
```

`message` is a JSON object. The log output is:

```
received message from redis: {"temp":81}
message is type object
stringified is type string
```

On the client, I have:

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(e.data)
  ...
};
```

The log output is:

> {"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,116,101,109,112,34,58,53,52,125]}

Why am I not receiving a string?

If on the server I hardcode:

```
client.send('foobar');
```

then the client code will log out:

> foobar

Comment: Your whole log output could be a JSON string.  Try `console.log(typeof e.data)` in the client and see if it tells you it is a string.  Also, please make the title of your question more meaningful.

Comment: @jfriend00 Indeed `typeof e.data` is a string. I'm unclear how I should be processing this. Why the discrepancy between a stringified JSON object and a basic string? Cheers.

Comment: My issue is `message` from Redis isn't a string, but when I call `console.log('received message from redis: ' + message);` then `toString()` was being called implicitly. I was being lazy and didn't hook up a proper inspector so `console.log` wasn't showing me what I needed to see.

Comment: In the future, you can do: `console.log('received message from redis: ', message);` instead of `console.log('received message from redis: ' + message);` and you will see the whole object instead of only a `.toString()` conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the fact that any kind of socket-based communication in Node is based on Buffers (more precisely, on `Unit8Array`, a kind of TypedArray).

You can safely call `toString` on a Buffer to get a string, or use Streams to make any kind of desired transformations on received data.

*Edit:* BTW, when you try to `console.log` a Buffer, it's `toString` method will be called implicitly.

Comment: Looks like this was user error on my part, but I have no doubt you are indeed correct!